# Screenshots not created under test-output folder in TestNG, Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am new to Selenium WebDriver. I am using the following method to take screenshots of failed tests in Selenium, TestNG. After execution, the testNG report shows the failed tests perfectly and also the imageFile outputfile is successfully created, but no screenshots appear under test-output folder. When I manually checked, I found that the screenshots were being created outside the test-output folder, in the project folder. How do I rectify this, so that the screenshots appear under test-output folder?

```
@AfterMethod 
public void closeBrowser(ITestResult result) throws IOException {
    if (!result.isSuccess()){
        File imageFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        String failureImageFileName = result.getMethod().getMethodName()+new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy_HH-ss").format(new GregorianCalendar().getTime()) + ".png";
        File failureImageFile = new File(failureImageFileName);
        FileUtils.copyFile(imageFile, failureImageFile);

    }
```

Comment: `result.getMethod().getMethodName()+new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy_HH-ss").format(new GregorianCalendar().getTime()) + ".png";` Where did you specify the test-output folder in here?

Comment: No failureImageFileName is just the format of the file name I require. I guess the location of the file to be stored has something to do with TestNG settings. By default, the screenshots should have been saved under test-output folder, like index.html. Am really new to selenium, and kinda taking time to figure out things!!

Answer (score 0):

```
public void closeBrowser(ITestResult result) throws IOException {
    if (!result.isSuccess()){
        File imageFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        String failureImageFileName = result.getMethod().getMethodName()+new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy_HH-ss").format(new GregorianCalendar().getTime()) + ".png";

        // It will store all the screenshots in test-output/screenshots folder
        String destDir = System.getProperty("user.dir")) + "/" + "test-output/screenshots";
        new File(destDir ).mkdirs();
        String destFile = destDir + "/" + failureImageFileName;
        FileUtils.copyFile(imageFile, new File(destFile ));
    }
```